# Explicit Invocation that bypasses welcome message

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm not sure if this is due to the Dialogflow testing environment, or if there is something else I am missing.

I have app ABC that has a default welcome message "hi" and also some intents for specific responses. I would like the user to be able to invoke a response by saying "Hey Google, ask ABC what is it's favorite color?" and have the intent passed to ABC. However, instead of answering the "what is your favorite color?" ABC responds with the default "hi".

Can I fix this or does the app have to first pass through the welcome message?

Comment: Can you update your question to show screen shots about how you've configured the Intents that you want to answer the "favorite color" question, a screen shot of the Integration Settings for the Assistant, and more details about how you're testing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **integrations** section of Dialogflow check your **integration settings** for your Google Assistant action. There is a section there to add **implicit invocations** where you can select other intents that should be able to launch your app. Select the intents you want and then these should work

Comment: @user2630947 If you found the answer helpful and it worked please click the tick the check mark so others know it worked and is the accepted answer

Comment: thanks. I upvoted it but then it said I wasn't allowed to do that so I assumed the same for the checkmark and didn't click it.